# Highlight an element within the target element of an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor

I'm currently using the following to attempt to highlight an element (div.box) that is inside the targeted element of an anchor (example, section#help).  The anchor is used to scroll to #help, but I only need to highlight the div.box that is in the #help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".box").removeClass("highlightTarget");
var myLocation = document.location.hash.replace("#","");
if (myLocation) {
    document.getElementById(myLocation).className = "highlightTarget";
}

$("a").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass("highlightTarget");
    var clickedLink = this.href.split("#");
    if (clickedLink.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById(clickedLink[1]).className = "highlightTarget";
    }
});
```

});

Together with the css:

```
.highlightTarget {background:red}
```

Currently, my code changes the background of the section#help red.  What am I doing wrong?

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you for is the `.box` element inside the target element, so you need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find) inside the target element to find the `.box` element.

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass("highlightTarget");
    var clickedLink = this.href.split("#");
    if (clickedLink.length > 1) {
        $('#' + clickedLink[1]).find('.box').addClass("highlightTarget")
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, and what do I need to add or change so that the highlight also happens to the child element when the user accesses the page via a URL that contains the anchor?  i.e. faq.php#help

Comment: BTW, `'#' + clickedLink[1]` is the same as just `this.href`.

Comment: @Barmar I must be doing something wrong, as its not working for me.

Comment: `if (myLocation) { $('#' + myLocation).find('box').addClass("highlightTarget"); }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").removeClass("highlightTarget");
var myLocation = document.location.hash.replace("#","");
if (myLocation) {
    document.getElementById(myLocation).className = "highlightTarget";
}

$("a").click(function () {
    $(".box").removeClass("highlightTarget");
    var clickedLink = this.href.split("#");
    if (clickedLink.length > 1) {
        $('#' + clickedLink[1]).find('.box').addClass('highlightTarget');
    }
});
```